# Since the horizon of a Nonstationary isolated black hole is a closed surface, how can gravitational waves be generated?

Tags: black-holes, gravitational-waves, event-horizon

I understand this is from numerical calculations in GR. I have not seen them. Can anyone elucidate on what generates the GW waves - I know that deformities (anything moments higher than dipole) will radiate, but what is a moment in the horizon, when the matter that caused it already is inside and disappeared? Is there a good, physically illuminating way to understand the process?

Comment: Acceleration. Like accelerating charges generates electromagnetic waves,  accelerating mass generates gravitational waves. The matter inside does not generate the waves we observe, the black hole as a whole (event horizon including) does that.

Answer (score 1):

For eternal black holes (and eternal black holes don't exist) the gravitational wave is generated by the metric outside the black hole.

For an astrophysical black hole, there isn't any matter "already inside" the horizon and the metric and the spacetime "outside" the horizon (we should really call it the spacetime "before" the horizon, except that wouldn't make sense for an eternal black hole, the ones that don't exist) extends all the way to the center, but always from *before* the event horizon formed.

> what is a moment in the horizon, when the matter that caused it already is inside and disappeared?

If it formed from matter, then the action of the matter before the horizon forms affects the outgoing waves. But you don't need matter to make a wave. Two eternal black holes orbiting each other generate waves even though neither formed from matter. And two astrophysical black holes that orbit each other can produce nearly identical waves because the metric away from the matter can be very close to an eternal black hole metric outside its horizon.

It will be a tiny tiny bit different because the matter contributes too.

Comment: I think i follow. What of this case: As an astrophysical black hole is collapsing there's matter that Is producing GWs (through the Einstein equations,nonlinearly reinforced). At some point when the body is collapsing a horizon will form. That horizon is initially also highly asymmetrical, if the body was and did not settle to symmetric. the st is inside and outside the horizon. the matter, since it disappeared, no longer has any effect on the wave. For the GW that is released after the horizon forms, can any part of it be assumed as caused by the horizon conformal metric, i.e., coming from it

Comment: @BobBee There is no evidence a horizon forms.

Comment: Not sure if you mean it's an apparent horizon. But some horizon forms. Example: in GW20150914 there was a merged horizon after the BHs merged. So, in that very asymmetrical and dynamics horizon, as it settles to a Kerr metric, emits GWs (in ther

Comment: Continued - could not edit quickly. So I assume some horizon forms. After it does, there must be something like a ring down phase, emitting GWs. Does the GW cause Bondi mass loss to the BH, from rotational or other non-irreducible mass-energy term? Or is the question not well-posed?

Comment: @BobBee There are two kinds of black holes, the eternal ones with event horizons that have always been around. And the astrophysical ones that aren't technically black holes but are only called black holes since a little bit away from them the metric is really really really similar to the eternal black hole. It's not considered cool to keep them straight, but they are different; no matter how many people choose to oversimplify the situation. So we didn't see two black holes merge into one. We saw two things really similar to black holes merge into one thing that is similar to a larger one.

Comment: The "after" of an event horizon is called **the inside** and it is **not** some spatial surface that forms at some time. It's a boundary between two regions and the after of that boundary is **literally** the inside. When you are outside, then you are before. It really is that simple, I'm not simplifying at all. You could check out a Penrose diagram if you want.